# Is there a way to read a file that's within our project without needing a hardcoded path?

Tags: java

I have a few .dat files that my program reads for input and output. They are stored in the project folder. How would I read and write to these files, what would the path be?? I'd like to be able to zip up the project and send it off for others to use so I can't hard code a path because others may not place it in the same path

Right now I'm using the Scanner and File classes:

```
    String input= "E:\\CProj01\\input.dat";
    Scanner scannerInput = new Scanner(new File(input));
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes! You can use a `ClassLoader`

If you keep your files located in a relative place within the directory of your project, you can do something like this:

```
getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("relative file path here")
```

And then you can use the returned `InputStream` object to parse the file.

The `ClassLoader` allows you to keep all your files relative to the Project Root so if you had files organized like so:

```
src_
    |___files_
    |    -'yourfile.dat'
    |    -'anotherfile.dat'
    |___java_
```

Referencing `yourfile.data` with the `String` argument of `files/yourfile.dat` would always get you that file as a stream no matter where the package is deployed/downloaded/moved to.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, if you're sending it as Java project which they can use and edit then you can create a `resources` folder and you can simply get the file path like

```
String input= "src/resources/input.dat";
Scanner scannerInput = new Scanner(new File(input));
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try a JFileChooser.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JFileChooser.html